# variables not working in modular sass

Tags: sass, bootstrap-sass, grunt-contrib-sass, underscores-wp

I am using a modular SASS that came with Underscores (which is a WordPress framework but not really relevant here). It is very similar to what you see with bootstrap less or sass where you have one simple file that has a plethora of @import statements.

My problem is when I run my grunt task (grunt-contrib-sass) on the core style.scss I get an error stating undefined variable: "$color__background-body" in line 32 of sass/layout/_reset.scss. But I do have that variable defined in the very first @import. I fix that one and then it just has an issue with the next variable, so it isn't seeing my variables.

I had this same problem in the past with using bootstrap-less using Koala compiler and ended up not using variables. But I would like to resolve this so if any of you have any ideas I would love to hear them!

You can find the files and structure here:

https://github.com/shellwe/Great-Plains-Landscaping-WP/tree/master/sass

Also, I understand a fix could be to have all my variables in my style.scss instead of in an @import statement but I would like to keep with the modular feel if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Adding a comment to say that the current repo is no longer having that issue. Due to needing a resolution I removed some of the variables, converted some files to flat CSS, and for some strange reason having the reset.scss in the same folder and that helped. I am still uncertain as to why it was happening and if you pull up a version of the site from about 8 p..m on 3/29 you would see the error I am talking about.

Comment: In response to your comment, giving us a commit hash would be more helpful